# cannot add machine to DC

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, domain-controller

A have a lab that has some VM's:

- SrvDom: main DC / Server 2008 x64
- SrvSQL: SQL Server 2008 testing / Server 2003 x86
- SrvAppV: App-V testing / Server 2003 x64
- and other XP Clients

The SrvAppV cannot see the DC and vice-versa, so I cannot add the server to the domain.
If anyone has any idea, please tell me how to fix this...

**ipconfig /all** on SrvDom:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SrvDom
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : rigo.dom
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : rigo.dom

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-3F-86-7D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::85f6:70b8:607e:6629%12(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 251661353
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-D3-95-BE-00-0C-29-3F-86-7D
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : ::1
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{1929BE3C-ECD4-430A-B993-27DFA88E700D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

**ipconfig /all** on SrvSQL:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : srvsql
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : rigo.dom
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : rigo.dom

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-DC-A0-95
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.101
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100
```

**ipconfig /all** on SrvAppv:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : srvappv
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-68-B9-46
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.100
```

Comment: Are these all VMs, and are they on the same or multiple hosts? I'm assuming you've checked for IP conflicts since I see you're using static IPs.

Comment: When you say "The SrvAppV cannot see the DC", can you give us more specifics?

Comment: What @John said - are all of these on the same physical host? Which hypervisor are you using? Hypervisors can have multiple virtual networks that cannot communicate to eachother.

Comment: I concur with @John. Have you tried enabling DHCP on this server and seeing if it can join the domain? IP conflict looks like the culprit here.

Comment: @john: all are on the same host

Comment: @joeqwerty: if i ping the srvdom from srvappv i get no response

Comment: @mark: i'm using VMware Workstation 8, host OS is Win 7 x64

Comment: @RemusRigo - are all your VM's using the same network setup? I.E. they all using Bridged, or Host Only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked the network adapter for each VM and my srvappv machine was different from the others. It was set to NAT and the DC was set to bridged. So switched to bridged connection and that fixed the problem.